# finding a function with particular name

Tags: eclipse

How can i search for a function with particular name in my entire project.I dont even know if the function by that name exists.So i cant find references to that function by right clicking and then selecting the  required option.
For example in eclipse we have one short curt ctr + shift +R to search for all classes with particular name.
Ctr + 0 to search for function in current class.I want to search in entire workspace

---

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Java...` option in the `Search` menu.  The default options will search the entire workspace for all references and declarations of the search string. If you want to search only for declarations, there is a `Limit To` option.

Comment: Shortcut is typically CTRL-H to bring up that dialog.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + H` will give you the **full text search** of Eclipse.

In the tab `Java Search` you can specify to search for methods only (`Limit to`)  .
At the bottom you can also specify the `scope` of your search, in your case that would be *'Workspace'*.

If that does not suit your need type `Ctrl + Shift + L` twice, this opens the menu with the **list of all Eclipse hotkeys**.

There you can for example sort by category and browse all hotkeys in the `search` category. That will give you quite a good list of the possible search options you get withing eclipse.