# Search for a method in entire workspace including .class files and jar files. [Eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, search, methods

I have an Eclipse project with hundreds of jar files as reference libraries. I want to find the occurences of a particular method in my project including inside the jar files and the .class files within them.

I checked out about [finding a function with particular name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3727522/finding-a-function-with-particular-name), but that search only seems to search within .java files. Is there a way to accomplish this search within .jar and .class files.